# Oracle 11.2: Backup and recovery strategy based on full cold backup plus expdp

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, rman

Are there any issues with the following strategy for backup/recovery in Oracle 11.2.0.4?

1. Perform a full database cold backup once a month, moving the file off the server for safekeeping.
2. Write a cron job to perform `expdp` of all schemes except `SYS` daily, retaining only the last two weeks of files, and moving them off the server for safekeeping.
3. In the event of a failure, perform full database recovery using the cold backup, then do an `impdp` from the latest file (to restore all schemas except `SYS`). I can accept losing all database data since the last `expdp` file was taken (which is 24 hours, worst case).

The strategy is based on the belief that as long as I don't write or change anything in `SYS` schema since the full cold backup, that only changes to the other schemas need to be recovered after the restoring the full (cold) backup. Is that correct?

Comment: There are a number of reasons why expdp is a poor substitute for archivelog mode + RMAN hot backups.  The biggest reason is: point in time recovery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend taking weekly RMAN hot full backups and daily RMAN incremental backups as well as retaining archivelogs for at least 1 week.

The issue with using expdp/impdp is that it can and will create inconsistent snapshots of your schema during the hot backup process (unless you do a cold backup daily...which is not very practical). If you happen to lose your entire database and begin to recover using impdp, you're at the mercy of the exports to be logically consistent which is only possible if no inserts, updates, or deletes happened at the time of the expdp export. You'll get data, but you can't guarantee that all the tables will be consistent with one another.

Your weekly hot backup will provide you a new "ground truth" database backup that will have guaranteed consistency after applying enough recovery to push through the database changes after the end of the hot backup. You can either use archivedlogs or incremental backups to apply recovery.

A daily incremental backup will speedup mean-time-to-recovery in the event that you do need to make a restore happen. Incremental backups recover faster than archivedlogs. On their own, incremental backups are meaningless without some sort of full backup that preceded them.

To this statement:

> The strategy is based on the belief that as long as I don't write or change anything in SYS schema since the full cold backup, that only changes to the other schemas need to be recovered after the restoring the full (cold) backup. Is that correct?

You're technically correct with the information you're providing. However, above I point out a critical flaw about the schema that makes this information irrelevant. That flaw is that you cannot guarantee data integrity with an expdp export without making it a cold export, and being cold is not advantageous for anyone.

Comment: Thanks @JoshBonello, do you know if I need to do anything special if I configure RMAN to do hot backups to prune old archive redo log files, or does Oracle entirely manage that so the number of files doesn't continue to grow past the last few (3?) weeks?

Comment: You will be required to manage the storage of your archivedlogs. There are RMAN prompts to backup and purge archivelogs but you can also manage them from the OS like any other files. Oracle takes no automatic stance on purging. A cron script (using either RMAN or OS tools) would fulfill your need nicely.

Comment: `expdp` options for creating a consistent export dump: `FLASHBACK_SCN`, `FLASHBACK_TIME`, `CONSISTENT=Y`. Automatic purging of archivelogs in FRA can be enabled by setting the archivelog deletion policy in RMAN, for example: `CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO backed up 1 times to disk;`.

Comment: @BalazsPapp I understand `CONSISTENT=Y` will give a consistent write, but that requires locking of all the tables in the schema for the duration of the backup. This will prevent writes, although it does allow reads. This is not a sustainable solution for backups unless the database is very small with no plans for growth. Good info on the FRA, I was ambiguous. It can be automated by Oracle, but it is not automated by default.

Comment: @Josh Bonello It does not require locking. It uses undo data, works like flashback query.

Comment: @JoshBonello, how would know which archive redo log files can be safely deleted?

Comment: @BalazsPapp Thanks for the clarification. I didn't realize dp had made that pretty massive improvement over exp. user46688 If the archived redo log was written at any time before the beginning of a full RMAN backup, you're safe to purge it.

Comment: @user46688 - as long as I don't write or change anything in SYS schema since the full cold backup - You shouldn't write or change anything is SYS, but Oracle internal processes will, all the time. I see no reason to complicate your life with this strategy, use RMAN instead.